# Dataframe with space

Tags: r, dataframe

I am uploading several .xlsx files and creating a data frame from each worksheet. The issue is that the worksheets have a space (" ") in the name (ie. Survey 1, Survey 2, Survey 3...etc). When I separate out each worksheet as it's own dataframe, it keeps the space (" ") and they are pretty useless after that. Is there a way to remove the space in the dataframe name? or replace the space with a dash ("-"), period("."), or underscore("_")? Although the easy option would be to manually rename on the .xslx file, was hoping there was a way to do it via R to automate the process.

This is the code I'm using:

```
df<- excel_sheets("2021-Fish-Survey-Data-Final.xlsx")
df_name <- lapply(df, function(x) read_excel("2021-Fish-Survey-Data-Final.xlsx", sheet = x))
names(df_name) <- df
list2env(df_name, envir=.GlobalEnv)
```

I've tried incorporating the code(s) below in various ways, but I can't seem to figure it out
`gsub("\\s+", "", df)`

and/or

`gsub("\\s+", "", df_name)`

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with `list2env(df_name, envir=.GlobalEnv)`? Do you want to combine all data frames in the list to a single one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there. I think with `gsub(" ", "", sheet_names, fixed = TRUE)` it should work.

```
library(readxl)
                              # system-dependent path
sheet_names <- excel_sheets("./2021-Fish-Survey-Data-Final.xlsx"))
ls_df <- lapply(sheet_names, \(x) read_excel("2021-Fish-Survey-Data-Final.xlsx", sheet = x))
names(ls_df) <- gsub(" ", "", sheet_names, fixed = TRUE)
```

which gives

```
> ls_df
$Survey1
# A tibble: 0 × 0

$Survey2
# A tibble: 0 × 0
```

For clarity, I have changed the names of objects: `sheet_names` := names of excel sheets; `ls_df` := list containing each sheet as data frame.

[image]